# How to fix tailwind disappear problem when loading project in server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a react project. And i used fuse-react template which uses tailwindcss in that. Hovewer, when i publish the project on server pages are not looking properly since tailwindcss not loading, it disappeares. I watch the network but i never see the tailwindcss. Is there any solution?

i tried to add tailwind manually or used some npm or yarn packages to solve but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you check out the [installation section](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) of the Tailwind CSS docs?

Pretty sure you're missing the necessary PostCSS-config or something along those lines.